# Strange lines appearing on Android Studio design view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

Personally I have no problem with Android Studio, but one of the people on my course is having a strange problem with the design view. Lines and boxes keep appearing and are causing problems and after researching profusely for the last couple of hours I've been able to find no mention of what they are or how to get rid of them anywhere on the internet.

I found one other stack overflow post about these that had been submitted a couple of months ago, however it unfortunately featured no replies. I've added the screenshot from this post just to save me getting one but it's the same problem.

Does anybody know how to get rid of these? Or what they are? Because they don't show on my Android Studio.

[The screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qA2S.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe it just some bugs appeared on install? 
Try to just:
1. File - > clear cache and exit
2. Reinstall studio
3. Install studio 3.0 in early access

Hope it will help)

Comment: Thank you, we tried a couple of things with this being one of them - the problem seems to have gone so it's a possibility that this fixed it. Thanks.